# Display / Render an HTML file inside Jupyter Notebook on Google Colab platform

Tags: python, google-maps, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

I am using Google Colab to work create maps with Python 3.0 and I have done so using Basemaps. I am next trying to create similar maps using Google Maps. There are two python packages that I have located namely gmaps and gmplot. It seems as if gmaps requires a google API but gmplot does not hence I am using gmplot.

With gmplot, I am able to create a file 'my_map.html' which if I download to my local desktop, I can open in a browser and see the map correctly.

However I would like to see the map in the notebook output cell without downloading to the local machine. The following image is a screenshot of what I have tried ... there is no error, but no display either.
[image: screenshot]

is there some command like %matplotlib inline that i need execute to be able to display the contents of the file in the output cell? or is there a better solution

Comment: I would suggest looking in your browser's console output because this function works fine for me. You can even test it by writing and displaying your own html file.

Answer (score 14):

Try full path to your file: `/content/my_map.html`

The code should be:

```py
import IPython
IPython.display.HTML(filename='/path/to/your/filename')
```

Answer (score 6):

Please Try Following code:

```py
from IPython.display import IFrame
IFrame(src='path/to/your/filename.html', width=900, height=600)
```

It did work for me. :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your answer doesn't appear to add anything more than the other answers. The only difference is the the explicit dimensional specification, which doesn't appear relevant to the question. Is there some explanation or more content you could add to your post to improve it? New answers that don't add anything tend to get downvoted or removed.

Comment: An iframe is different from just displaying html.  Granted you can probably get to iframe from regular html, but it's a different approach from the other options.

Answer (score 5):

This solution is not working for me if the html contains images located on colab or in your (mapped) google-drive:

```
IPython.display.HTML('<img src="/content/elmo_1.jpg">') # can't find image 
IPython.display.HTML('<img src="/content/gdrive/My Drive/elmo_1.jpg">') # can't find image  
IPython.display.HTML('<img src="/content/gdrive/My%20Drive/elmo_1.jpg">') # can't find image
```

It works, however, with standard url:

```
IPython.display.HTML('<img src="https://github.com/blablabla/elmo_1.jpg?raw=1">')
```

Answer (score 0):

Colab won't display local file images in html. You need to convert a png file to base64

```
encoded = base64.b64encode(open(png_file_name, "rb").read())
```

And show image using

```
<img src=f"data:image/png;base64,{encoded.decode('utf-8')}" alt="" width="600" height="400">
```