# How can i view an html output file from a gmplot draw command inside of a Google Colab notebook?

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, gmplot

I am trying to use colab and googlemaps to display a heatmap image overlayed onto google maps. I did some research and found 2 possible solutions at this link but both solutions are not working.

[Display / Render an HTML file inside Jupyter Notebook on Google Colab platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51576756/display-render-an-html-file-inside-jupyter-notebook-on-google-colab-platform)

Maybe something has changed recently?
Here is my code:

```
pip install gmplot
import gmplot 
gmap1 = gmplot.GoogleMapPlotter(30.3164945, 
                                78.03219179999999, 13, apikey='AIzaSyBCyhpxDYIxIq9uINYxDK5aIjWSokUvsvY' ) 
gmap1.draw( "map11.html" ) 
import os
print(os.getcwd())
!ls

/content
map11.html  sample_data

import IPython
IPython.display.HTML(filename='/content/map11.html')

nothing is displayed. 

from IPython.display import IFrame
IFrame(src='/content/map11.html', width=900, height=600)

localhost refused to connect.
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your local browser cannot read a file from the remote VM filesystem. Instead of passing the HTML by filename, try displaying the HTML content directly:

```
IPython.display.HTML(open('/content/map11.html').read())
```

Comment: I tried this suggestion but still can't see any html output. I tested this further by putting a html file in my google drive and I am able to see that file from my colab notebook. Maybe this is a permissions issue?  
<pre>IPython.display.HTML(open('/content/map11.html').read())  

from google.colab import drive

drive.mount('/content/drive')

!ls -rlt /content/drive/My\ Drive

IPython.display.HTML(open('drive/My Drive/package-summary.html').read())

Comment: If that code works and my answer doesn't, it means that the file contents differ between drive and the original path. It's not a permissions issue: the only difference is the content of the two files.

Comment: Yes, it seems that colab notebooks are having problems handling and displaying the google maps javascript function in the html file from gmplot. I can add normal text inside the html file and the text shows up, but the map does not. If i copy this to my local drive, i can see the map.

Comment: ...
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=visualization&sensor=true_or_false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 function initialize() {
  var centerlatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(30.316495, 78.032192);
  var myOptions = {
   zoom: 13,
   center: centerlatlng,
   mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

 }
</script>
</head>
<body style="margin:0px; padding:0px;" onload="initialize()">
 <div id="map_canvas" ..."></div>
...

Comment: Here is a link to the original document:  
  
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Y7OzkbyUm3NlPrjJDME4Ddrk52DNWYpE/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I found out that the google api is not producting any visible output, so the screen is blank when displaying the html output. I had to use a different mapping package to get this working.

Comment: Which package did you use?