# html inside code cell jupyterlab vs google colab

Tags: google-colaboratory, jupyter-lab

google colab can contain code cell content like

```
#@title <font color="orange">**Restart Runtime**</font>
#@markdown Click this if `Clean Environment Up` does not work
import os
os.kill(os.getpid(), 9)
```

It can also contain sliders i've seen in some stable difusion examples.
If I would like to such jupyternotebooks inside my own jupyterlab then what needs to be installed to allow for those html alike rendering of those code cells ?.

Comment: For clarify, do you want to render HTML code in Google Colab? - if so, you can use `import IPython` - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/55329863/12511801

Comment: eh no the opposite, i wanted to use a google colab jupyter notebook at my own hardware, but i have jupyterlab.